# Woocommerce - Product category – out of stock limit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How can I achieve that the product category will display first all “In Stock” products and then only the last 10 “Out of stock”?

I know that in the Admin Panel, I need to uncheck the option “Out of stock visibility”.

What code should I include, to display only the last 10 out-of-stock products at the end of the list?

```
function woo_product_query( $q ) {
    $q->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $q->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'modified' => 'DESC' )  );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'woo_product_query' );
```

Comment: That will probably be rather hard to achieve with just _one_ query. (You would need to know the number of in-stock products beforehand, so that you can use that number plus 10 as LIMIT value, to get the correct amount of records within the sorted data set.)

Comment: How can I calculate it? Any subquery?

Comment: Probably, yes. But that again will likely be hard to hack together using `$q->set` functionality ... Might be rather one of those rare cases in WP, where it could make more sense to write the SQL directly.

Comment: I made something like that: https://pastebin.com/b5Zj2bg7 , how can I implement a limit to the query?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters - `posts_per_page`

Comment: Additionally, this requires some UX thinking, especially if the change from in stock and out of stock crosses pagination.

Comment: Yes, I would like know, how to do that with pagination